# pthread_join() hangs in stress test

Tags: c, pthreads

I am running a phread test program until it fails. Here is the main skeleton of the code:

```
int authSessionListMutexUnlock()
{
    int rc = 0;
    int rc2 = 0;

    rc2 = pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutex);
    ERR_IF( rc2 != EBUSY && rc2 != 0 );

    rc2 = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    ERR_IF( rc2 != 0 );

    cleanup:

    return rc;  
}

static void cleanup_handler(void *arg)
{
    int rc = 0;

    (void)arg;

    rc = authSessionListMutexUnlock();
    if (rc != 0)
        AUTH_DEBUG5("authSessionListMutexUnlock() failed\n");
}


static void *destroy_expired_sessions(void *t)
{
    int rc2 = 0;

    (void)t;

    pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup_handler, NULL);

    rc2 = pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
    if (rc2 != 0)
        AUTH_DEBUG5("pthread_setcancelstate(): rc2 == %d\n", rc2);

    rc2 = pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, NULL);
    if (rc2 != 0)
        AUTH_DEBUG5("pthread_setcanceltype(): rc2 == %d\n", rc2);

    while (1)
    {
        ... // destroy expired session
        sleep(min_timeout);
    }
    pthread_cleanup_pop(0);
}

int authDeinit( char *path )
{
    ...
    rc2 = authSessionListDeInit();
    ERR_IF( rc2 != 0 );

    rc2 = pthread_cancel(destroy_thread);
    ERR_IF( rc2 != 0 );

    rc2 = pthread_join(destroy_thread, &status);
    ERR_IF( rc2 != 0 || (int *)status != PTHREAD_CANCELED );

    ...
    return 0
}
```

It runs well with the test program, but the test program hangs at round #53743 with pthread_join():

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x40000410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x0094aa77 in pthread_join () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x08085745 in authDeinit ()
    at /users/qixu/src/moja/auth/src//app/libauth/authAPI.c:1562
#3  0x0807e747 in main ()
    at /users/qixu/src/moja/auth/src//app/tests/test_session.c:45
```

Looks like pthread_join() caused a deadlock. But looking at the code, I feel there is no reason that a dead lock be caused by pthread_join(). When pthread_join() gets the chance to run, the only mutex operation is of the thread itself. Should be no conflict, right? Really confused here...

Comment: maybe your thread tries to join itself? That would deadlock surely ^)

Comment: @VictorSorokin: This shouldn't be the case, because the thread `destroy_thread` was created in a function other than `authDeinit()`. And if the thread tries to join itself, it will be deadlock in the first run, not after a long time, right?

Comment: What is `ERR_IF`? is this changing control flow?

Comment: @JensGustedt: Yeah, it is a error handling macro and it will change the control flow.

Comment: The answers and comments to those answers for this question are gold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least one "oddity" shows in your code; your cleanup handler will always unlock the mutex *even if you're not the thread holding it.*

From the manual;

> Calling pthread_mutex_unlock() with a mutex that the calling thread
>   does not hold will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: It's a long story, Joachim. The main purpose for this pthread_cancel() and pthread_join() is to let the cleanup handler unlock the mutex, which is used by the thread (calculating time and destroy the session that expires), to avoid a deadlock that may incur if any other function will use that mutex. And, if the mutex is already in unlocked status, `pthread_mutex_trylock()` will lock it, thus gain the control, and is followed with `pthread_mutex_unlock()`. Nothing is wrong here, is it?

Comment: @QiangXu The problem is if the mutex is locked by another thread (if it can't be, there's not much use for a mutex), in which case you'll trylock, not get a lock and unlock the mutex while another thread owns it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, Joachim. with your suggestion, I realized how dangerous it is to unlock a mutex in a thread cancellation cleanup handler. I guess the same applies to the memory issue. No wonder so many people are against using `pthread_cancel()` (even with a cleanup handler) when there are more than 1 threads running at the same time, operating on the same resources.

Comment: By the way, it is found that my problem is due to the initialization of the mutex to be a recursive one, so that in some rare occasions, `pthread_mutex_trylock()` locked the recursive mutex successfully, even though the mutex has been locked before. It just doesn't get a return value of EBUSY. But `pthread_mutex_unlock()` is only called once in the cleanup hander. So it hangs here. Nothing wrong with `pthread_join()`.

Comment: @QiangXu: There's nothing dangerous about unlocking a mutex in a cancellation handler. What's dangerous is having the wrong cancellation handlers installed at the wrong time. The scope of a cancelation handler that unlocks a mutex should be exactly the duration for which the mutex is locked and you're calling functions that are cancellation points. Its scope should end before the mutex is unlocked.

Comment: Note that the same issue would apply if your cancellation handler were calling `free` on a pointer that was not valid at the time the cancellation handler runs (e.g. because it was already freed).

Comment: @R..: Thanks for your comment, R. Still, if a mutex is initialized as recursive (means the same thread can lock it more than once), how could a cleanup handler unlock the mutex effectively? Looks a bit hard, coz pthread_mutex_trylock won't return EBUSY. :-(

Comment: @QiangXu You need to push an extra cleanup handler every time you lock the mutex and pop it at unlock, all pushed handlers will run if cancelled. The problem with _async_ cancel is that you may cancel anywhere, including when you just popped the cleanup handler but didn't unlock. You can call pthread_cleanup_pop() with a non zero parameter which will execute the cleanup handler when popping (and so unlock your mutex) but I'm not aware of any guarantee that that handler itself can't be cancelled. I'm sure someone else knows if that's the case :)

Comment: According to your design, the thread flow should be something like `lock -> push -> ... -> pop -> unlock`, isn't it? So, if pop has a non-zero argument, then in most cases, the mutex would be unlocked twice (first time when the cleanup handler is popped up, second time in the unlock following pop). Isn't it dangerous?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: The cleanup handler can't be cancelled when called with pop(1) unless it calls a cancellation point, or unless asynchronous cancellation is enabled. And if asynchronous cancellation is enabled, you are not permitted to call any functions in the standard library whatsoever except `pthread_setcancelstate`,  `pthread_setcanceltype`, and `pthread_cancel`, so you certainly can't lock or unlock mutexes.

Answer (score 3):

A bigger problem with your code, and probably the cause of the deadlocks, is your use of asynchronous cancellation mode (I missed this before). **Only 3 functions** in POSIX are async-cancel-safe:

- pthread_cancel()
- pthread_setcancelstate()
- pthread_setcanceltype()

Source: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_05_04

You certainly cannot lock and unlock mutexes while async cancel mode is enabled.

For async cancellation to be usable, you have to do one of the following things:

- Use it only with code that's purely computational, e.g. doing heavy math without any library calls at all, just arithmetic operations, or
- Constantly toggle it off and back on around each library call you make.

**Edit:** Based on the comments, I think you have a misunderstanding of what asynchronous cancellation type means. It has nothing to do with the manner in which cleanup handlers run. It's purely a matter of what point the thread can catch the cancellation request and begin acting on it.

When the target is in deferred cancellation mode, calling `pthread_cancel` on it will not necessarily do anything right away, unless it's already blocked in a function (like `read` or `select`) that's a cancellation point. Instead it will just set a flag, and the next time a function which is a cancellation point is called, the thread will instead block any further cancellation attempts, run the cancellation cleanup handlers in the reverse order they were pushed, and exit with a special status indicating that the thread was cancelled.

When the target is in asynchronous cancellation mode, calling `pthread_cancel` on it will interrupt the thread immediately (possibly between any pair of adjacent machine code instructions). If you don't see why this is potentially dangerous, think about it for a second. Any function that has internal state (static/global variables, file descriptors or other resources being allocated/freed, etc.) could be in inconsistent state at the point of the interruption: a variable partially modified, a lock halfway obtained, a resource obtained but with no record of it having been obtained, or freed but with no record of it having been freed, etc.

At the point of the asynchronous interruption, further cancellation requests are blocked, so there's no danger of calling whatever function you like from your cleanup handlers. When the cleanup handlers finish running, the thread of course ceases to exist.

One other potential source of confusion: cleanup handlers do not run in parallel with the thread being cancelled. When cancellation is acted upon, the cancelled thread stops running the normal flow of code, and instead runs the cleanup handlers then exits.

Comment: And note that even in the purely mathematical case, you'll *eventually* have to switch async cancellation off so you can inform other threads that the result is ready.

Comment: Isn't async cancellation designed to let the user cancel the thread whenever he wants? But if async cancellation cleanup handler can't unlock a mutex (or free a chunk of memory allocated before), it nearly is unuseful, is it?

Comment: Async cancellation must not be enabled until after you lock the mutex (you cannot call **any** library functions except the above 3 while it's enabled!) and must be disabled before you unlock the mutex. If you're in the cleanup handler due to cancellation, then async cancellability was already disabled by acting on a cancellation request (you won't get another cancellation during processing of the first one).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, R. So, it looks we better always keep the cancellation type at deferred, instead of async, if we want the cleanup handler to take effect. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: No, the the cancellation type you use has nothing to do with cleanup handlers. It pertains to what you can do in the main flow of code. With deferred cancellation mode, cancellation is only acted upon at certain particular function calls (mostly system calls that can block waiting for an event). If you're just stuck in a loop doing math, it will never be acted upon. On the other hand, async cancellation can be acted upon at any time, but this means you are not allowed to call any library functions because interrupting them asynchronously could leave the whole program in an inconsistent state.

Comment: Either way, if cancellation is acted upon, further cancellation requests will be blocked before the cleanup handlers are run, so you can use any functions you like from a cancellation cleanup handler.

Comment: Also note that `pthread_cleanup_push` and `pthread_cleanup_pop` are not legal to use while cancellation type is async. You must switch to deferred to use either of them; you can switch back to async afterwards if you like.

Comment: You said "so you can use any functions you like from a cancellation cleanup handler", but again as you said, if the cancellation type is async, no library call is allowed, so even the cleanup handler is called, it can do pretty much nothing, isn't it? By the way, how to break out from the loop of math functions with async cancellation handler, if no glibc library call is allowed?

Comment: Per POSIX, when acting on cancellation, before the cleanup handlers are invoked, cancellation type is set to deferred and cancellation state is set to disabled. Thus at the time the cleanup handlers run, you are no longer running under async cancellability.

Comment: As for doing long math under async cancel, it looks like: (1) install cleanup handler, (2) switch to async cancellation type, (3) do math, (4) switch back to deferred cancellation type, (5) pop the cleanup handler.

Comment: Even if the cancellation type is async, it will actually be switched to deferred when the cleanup handler is called, won't it? If that is the case, it looks like the cancellation type async can be scratched, can't it?

Comment: By the way, the cleanup handler would only be activated between step 4 and 5, even if the cancel request is received before step 4?

Comment: No. The cancellation handler can only be activated after step 2 but before step 4.

Comment: If the handler gets activated between step 2 and 4, the cancellation type would be automatically switched to deferred, right? So, why is step 4 necessary?

Comment: Because if the computation finishes and you need to return successfully, you must disable async cancellation before you can return! Otherwise a new cancellation request could arrive at step 5 (which is not async-cancel-safe) and crash your program (or worse).

Comment: Suppose a cancel request is received between step 2 and 4, that is, while in a loop of math computation. As you pointed out in the above, the cancellation type would be set to deferred, so the heavy math computation can't get canceled (because there is no blocking library calls involved), can it? So, can I conclude that async cancel is pretty useless?

Comment: No, you cannot conclude that. The cancellation request is **already acted upon** at this point. The cleanup handlers immediately run (with further cancellation requests ignored), and after they finish, the thread immediately terminates.

Comment: So, it means when an async cleanup handler is acted upon during heavy math computation, no other cancellation can come in and interfere, right? But if the math compuation is protected by mutex locked, how could an async cleanup handler unlock it safely?

Comment: The cleanup handler runs without any danger of cancellation, so of course it can unlock the mutex. I've updated my answer with some more detailed information. Hope it helps.

Comment: The picture is very clear now. Async cancellation can be activated at any time, so it is quite unsafe (easy to leave system calls in an inconsistent status), and is to be avoided whenever possible. It is not that async cancellation cleanup handler can't (is not able to) do any system call. Rather, it can do anything the user wants, but at his/her own risk. Conclusion: only use async cancellation in tasks not involved with any system call, and remember to switch back to deferred cancellation type after those tasks are finished (when system calls will come into play). Thanks so much, R!!!